# How to configure .htaccess for MediaWiki Short URL?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mediawiki

I'm having problems getting Short URLs working on my wiki.

My current wiki URL is: `example.com/w/index.php?title=Main_Page`

My desired URL is: `example.com/wiki/Main_Page`

I followed MediaWiki's [Apache Short URL Guide](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Short_URL/Apache) and [ShortURL Builder](https://shorturls.redwerks.org/) but neither work: `/wiki` and `/wiki/Main_Page` still return 404 Page Not Found.

Their recommended settings also resulted in my ENTIRE SITE being redirected to MediaWiki, which I did not want.

What I added to my `.htaccess` file (in web root folder, not `/w`):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?wiki(/.*)?$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/w/index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^/?$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/w/index.php [L]
```

Added to `/w/LocalSettings.php`:

```
$wgScriptPath = "/w";
$wgScriptExtension = ".php";
$wgArticlePath = "/wiki/$1";
$wgUsePathInfo = true;
```

What needs to be changed to get my short url working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it working using the settings from [this ShortURL tutorial](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Short_URL/wiki/Page_Title_--_.htaccess):

Added to `.htaccess` in root folder (*before* rules for other sites like Wordpress):

```
# BEGIN MediaWiki
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^wiki/(.*)$ w/index.php?title=$1 [PT,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^wiki/*$ w/index.php [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^wiki$ w/index.php [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
# END MediaWiki
```

Added to `LocalSettings.php`:

```
$wgScriptPath = "/w";
$wgArticlePath = "/wiki/$1";
$wgScriptExtension = ".php";
$wgUsePathInfo = true;
$wgResourceBasePath = $wgScriptPath;
```